# Copy image from local to persistence volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to copy an image to my persistence volume ( it's like a default image that i want from my application to use it when a user have no image so it comes with application static files )

So what i've done so far is creating the  `deployments.yml` file like that :

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests.yaml
      kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: webserver
    name: webserver
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy: {}
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        io.kompose.service: webserver
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests.yaml
          kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: webserver
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: example.com:5000/app
          name: webserver
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          - containerPort: 8000
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/src/app/static
              name: my-volume
        imagePullSecrets:
          - name: privateregcred
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
          - name: my-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: my-volume
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: my-volume
    name: my-volume
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 2Gi
  status: {}
```

Ofc this is just a part from the file ( that conserne my problem ), so when i run it it worked perfectly when i save any images and delete my webserver pod and recreate again the old images persists fine. 
and this is the result of `kubectl get pvc`

```
NAME           STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
my-volume   Bound    pvc-e76e8f50-8716-44fa-9d34-9d0b70ae9e4e   2Gi        RWO            standard       45m
```

But my problem is that i want to copy my default image to the volume, so i tried to do

`kubectl cp webServer/app/static/profilepics/default.png pvc/my-volume:/profilepics`

and always the same problem 
 `Error from server (NotFound): pods "wemet-volume" not found`

i tried to change the name add default as namespace and always the same result , am i doing somthing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You‘re trying to copy directly to a pvc named my-volume. Try to copy to the pods mounted volume like so: kubectl cp yourfile.png webserver:/usr/src/app/static/profilepics

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer, Kubectl cp works only with POD, So you'll need to copy the file to the PVC via a POD attached to the PVC

Comment: Yes that's seems logical, so my problem was with the understanding of how it works. Thank you very much bro you saved my day :)